# Azure - Restrict Role Assignments to Managed Identities and Service Principals

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

Our Azure engineers need to be able to manage the identity and permissions used to run the software they deploy to the cloud.

However, granting them the ability to assign RBAC roles also allows them to assign permissions for any AD User or Group--not just system identities (Managed Identities, Service Principals).

How can I configure Azure to allow engineers to grant permissiona for their software to operate but prevent them from granting permissions to other AD entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource Policy can accomplish this, by inspecting the `principalType` value and the id of the role being assigned.

By assigning the policy with a list of specific role Ids (GUIDs) to allow or block role assignments of Contributor can be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Currently is not possible to limit the scope or selection of principals (users or services/applications) to be assigned roles. Usually, developers are given up to the [Contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) which give them access to almost all management features but user access while selected users are given the [User Access Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) role.

Comment: We are actually exploring using Resource Policy, we haven't fully vetted it yet and anticipate some gaps.  But it looks like we can potentially restrict assignments to at least service lrucinilz